# How to obtain live rates using currencylayer python

Tags: python, api, module, real-time, currency

I am making a realtime currency converter and need help.I have installed the following modules on python 3.5.2. PIP , currencylayer , urllib3,requests and simplejson.
I am obtaining errors that i do not understand when using sample code used to test currencylayer

```
    import requests

    response = requests.get(
     'http://jsonrates.com/get/?'+
     'from=USD'+
     '&to=EUR'
              )
     json = response.json()
     rate = float(json['rate'])
```

please can you help me understand and use this code so than i can use the currencylayer api to obtain realtime rates.

Cheers

Comment: If possible is to possible to tell me any other ways of obtaining realtime rates using diffrent methods that use less lines of code when i fully complete my code

Comment: "I am obtaining errors that i do not understand" is not very helpful. Please read [ask] and [mcve].